# Why are digits being omited from a column when importing a data file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to import data from a github site that is in csv form with pandas. It seems to be working fine, except that the column "ZIP" is not importing with all digits. There should be 5 digits for a zip code, but it seems that 1 or 2 digits from the front are being omitted. Why?!

I want to import [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erichurst/7882666/raw/5bdc46db47d9515269ab12ed6fb2850377fd869e/US%2520Zip%2520Codes%2520from%25202013%2520Government%2520Data) data:

```
coords=pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erichurst/7882666/raw/5bdc46db47d9515269ab12ed6fb2850377fd869e/US%2520Zip%2520Codes%2520from%25202013%2520Government%2520Data')
coords.head(5)
```

For some reason it looks like this, but the zip SHOULD be ***00601***

```
    ZIP     LAT         LNG
0   601     18.180555   -66.749961
```

Comment: @DavidBuck Nice, and an answer by Wes McKinney himself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because pandas automatically infers the `dtype` of your columns and ends up assigning `integer` dtype for the ZIP column, since it is composed by numbers only.

You have to explicitly state that they are strings otherwise `00601` will just be `601`

You can do that by using the`dtypes` argument in `read_csv`

```
pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'ZIP': str})
```